# El uso de "comerse"

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Qué diferencias hay entre las oraciones siguientes :

1. Así que empezaron a comerse las paredes de la casa.
2. Así que empezaron a comer las paredes de la casa.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

La primera es una expresión que significa que no les quedaba nada para comer o bien que tienen mucha hambre y no pueden esperar x tiempo. 
Indica un estado de ansiedad o desesperación. Nadie come paredes, y con la forma reflexiva la frase no pretende decir que nadie se las coma, sino que los sujetos hacen "locuras", acciones descabelladas .. llevados por el hambre o la situación desesperada. 
El sentido de la frase es, según el contexto, "estaban muy ansiosos o desesperados".

La segunda frase, pese a ser correcta, no tiene uso posible (en español). Nadie come paredes.

Comment: Imaginemos el cuento de Hansel y Gretel, en el que los niños (se) comen las paredes de la casita de chocolate... ¿Cuál es la diferencia ahí? Yo sé que es mejor con "se", pero no sé explicar por qué...

Comment: A raíz de la respuesta de leonbloy, añadiría que comerse puede interpretarse como 'alimentarse a si mismo' (con las paredes de la casita de chocolate). Y con esta interpretación sí podría considerarse 'comerse' como 'reflexivo de interés'. "Comen paredes" tendría un sentido de morderlas, mientras que "Se comen las paredes" tendría un sentido de "se alimentan con las paredes". ¿Qué tal así? Gracias a leonbloy por el link, muy interesante.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con MikMik solo que en un sentido un poco más estricto: la cordura, interpretación o sensatez de las oraciones de la pregunta es irrelevante, en realidad va encaminada al uso del lenguaje.

Comment: I am not quite understand your discussions. Acutually this example is taken from "Hansel and Gretel". Does it mean that "comerse"is to emphasize the behaviour of eating wall due to hungry? So "se" here is the function of dative interest?

Comment: @Cadenza El caso de "Hansel y Gretel" es especial. En español se usa la expresión "comerse las paredes" en sentido figurado (metafórico), y si no tengo mal entendido proviene del cuento original de Hansel y Gretel. El uso en el cuento, por ser un cuento, debe interpretarse literalmente, al igual que diríamos "David y María empezaron a comerse el bocadillo del desayuno". Desde esta otra perspectiva (literal), la explicación más clara es la de "pronombre se usado para indicar un proceso". "Así que empezaron a comerse las paredes" como en inglés dirías "So they started eating the walls".

Comment: En esta página http://www.appstate.edu/~fountainca/1050/unidad2/losusosdese.html, en la sección "se proceso", está muy bien explicado.

Answer (score 5):

La diferencia es que la primera es la forma pronominal, y es la forma correcta, porque la acción de comer recaen sobre algo específico, es decir, sobre un objeto directo determinado.

Si quitamos el objeto directo,  el pronominal se convierte en reflexivo, lo que resulta en un disparate **porque necesariamente falta algo**:

> Así que empezaron a comerse.

Mientras la forma no pronominal puede ir sin objeto directo:

> Así que empezaron a comer.

O con un objeto indeterminado, pero no un objeto concreto:

> Las termitas comen madera. (correcto)
>      Las termitas **se** comen madera. (**incorrecto**)
>      Las termitas comen mesa. (incorrecto)
>      Las termitas **se** comen la mesa. (**correcto**)

Comment: I dont understand this "Si quitamos el objeto directo, el pronominal se convierte en reflexivo, lo que resulta en un disparate porque necesariamente falta algo". Could you please explain more?

Comment: @Cadenza, sin el objeto directo "Así que empezaron a comerse" significa que "ellos" comieron a ellos mismos (reflexivo) lo que no tiene sentido (a menos que "ellos" fueran una tribu de caníbales).

Comment: I've got it. Why is "Las termitas se comen madera" not correct and "Las termitas se comen la mesa" is correct?

Comment: @Cadenza", "Wood" is an abstract concept. "The table" is a concrete object. Placed in a normal context, "Las termitas comen madera" could mean that the teacher of biology say  that "The food of the termites is any type of wood" whereas "Las termitas se comen **la** madera" could mean that "The f...g termites that invaded my house are destroying my furniture".

Comment: It'd be more didactic to compare "Las termitas se comen la mesa" with "Las termitas comen la mesa". The only difference between the two sentences should be the reflexive pronoun "se".

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Didáctico, sí, mientras tengas claro que la segunda frase no es correcta. Y por  "correcta" no me refiero a que, a veces, se use de esta forma, pero esté mal. No, es que no se usa, y punto.

Answer (score 0):

Comerse no solo indica comer algo sino que indica comerlo todo.