# Origen de la expresión "comerse el marrón"

Tags: etimología, expresiones, modismos, coloquialismos, españa

Hoy estaba con una amiga española como yo, criadas ambas en la misma zona pero ella mucho mayor que yo, y dije la expresión

> **Comerse el marrón**

que se usa en conversaciones informales para [indicar](https://dle.rae.es/marr%C3%B3n) el tener que cargar con una culpa o con un problema, situación o obligación molesta, desagradable o embarazosa.

Mi amiga no la conocía y tuve que explicarle lo que era. ¿Alguien puede decir cuándo y cómo surgió esta expresión?

Mi amiga es de principios de los años 30 y yo soy de los 80, siempre la he oído pero me he dado cuenta de que no puede ser tan antigua como me pensaba.

Comment: No encuentro ningún caso de la expresión en el CORDE, y en el CREA el más antiguo es de 1995. No parece que sea demasiado antigua.

Comment: sabes cómo surgió, suena a 'comerse la mierda' por el color y demás, pero espero que no sea así

Comment: A mí me suena a castañas.

Comment: Estoy investigando, en la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España el caso más antiguo es de 1981. Desde luego a mí tambien me suena a que es un eufemismo de "mierda", me extrañaría que fuera otra cosa de hecho.

Comment: La referencia más antigua que encuentro es en la película "Colegas" de 1982. Aquí tenéis el link a la película: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y4c37ImGdAc, en el minuto 9:08 dice "ya verás qué marrón te vas a comer".

Comment: Creo que en este caso hay que aplicar el principio de la navaja de Ockham y decir que la teoría más simple es la correcta. A algunas expresiones de ese tipo sí se les puede localizar bien el origen. La expresión "liarla pardo" viene de un vídeo que se hizo viral (una socorrista que mezcló los productos inadecuados para la piscina) y se popularizó mucho. "Comerse el marrón" no sé hasta qué punto es rastreable (y de serlo lo mismo nos llevamos una sorpresa respecto al origen), pero creo que es básicamente argot popular y coloquial con el significado que expresa Charlie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según https://www.defensacentral.com/ustedpregunta/categoria/gramatica/cual-es-el-origen-de-la-expresion-comerse-un-marron/ no tiene que ver con el color, sino con marro, un juego.

Aunque según https://www.curistoria.com/2012/05/origen-del-dicho-comerse-un-marron.html, tiene varios siglos de antiguedad, surgió en Salamanca y tiene que ver con cargar troncos o vigas (marrones) de algunas construcciones

Answer (score 0):

Yo he oído otra teoría en un programa concurso en la tv sobre lenguaje coloquial, un concurso bien documentado, así que le doy cierta credibilidad. Apareció esta frase y según el programa, viene del argot carcelario: las notificaciones de las condenas a los presos venían en una cartulina de color marrón.
La explicación del marrón glacé no me parece nada probable porque esta expresión es relativamente moderna, yo la empecé a oir allá por los años 80.
Ver https://revistagaleradas.com/

Answer (score -1):

La expresión proviene de la I Guerra Mundial, con casi toda probabilidad de la Batalla de Verdún, en Francia. Una parte fundamental para las tropas aliadas era asegurar el perímetro de las trincheras por la noche, una misión tan arriesgada como necesaria. Cuando los ánimos empezaron a mermar entre los soldados, el general Nivelle decidió recompensar a los que llevaran a cabo las misiones con “marron glacé”, una delicia que el general ofrecía de su bolsillo y de su despensa personal. Es por eso que al principio los soldados se ofrecían voluntarios con mayor frecuencia para estas misiones, diciendo contentos “hoy me como un marron”. Poco a poco, aunque iban cediendo en la batalla, los alemanes comenzaron a capturar y a matar un alto porcentaje de los exploradores franceses que cada noche salían a inspeccionar la zona cercana a las trincheras, por eso la expresión comenzó a difundirse con un significado negativo, como queriendo decir que el “marron” no compensaba el alto riesgo de la misión.

Comment: Bienvenido/a al sitio! Interesante teoría, ¿puedes enlazar a alguna fuente que la corrobore?